# Does smtp.SendMailAsync(message) runs in new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, email, asynchronous

Does Async functions runs in new thread. And it continues with normal execution.

```
smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
```

If there are 100 messages in the Message list: msgList, and we put foreach for that, Is it that it will create 100 threads and will run parallely.

```
foreach (var item in msgList)
{
    smtp.SendMailAsync(item);
}
```

Please explain me, and also the performance issues.
And please let me know if there is a better way to send mass emails at once.

Comment: I had this problem before,You can run a WCF service and use that

Answer (score 0):

[SendMailAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and all methods that use the Task Parallel Library execute in a threadpool thread, although you can make them use a new thread if you need to. This means that instead of creating a new thread, an available thread is picked from the pool and returned there when the method finishes.

The number of threads in the pool varies with the version of .NET and the OS, the number of cores etc. It can go from 25 threads per core in .NET 4 to hundreds or per core in .NET 4.5 on a server OS.

An additional optimization for IO-bound (disk, network) tasks is that instead of using a thread, an IO completion port is used. Roughly, this is a callback from the IO stack when an IO operation (disk or network) finishes. This way the framework doesn't waste a thread waiting for an IO call to finish.

When you start an asynchronous network operation, .NET make the network call, registers for the callback and releases the threadpool thread. When the call finishes, the framework gets notified and schedules the rest of the asynchronous method (essentially what comes after the `await` or `ContinueWith`) on a threadpool thread.

Submitting a 100 asynchronous operations doesn't mean that 100 threads will be used nor that all 100 of them will execute in parallel. Rather, the framework will take into account the number of cores, the load and the number of available threads to execute as many of them as possible, without hurting overall performance. Waiting on the network calls may not even use a thread at all, while processing the messages themselves will execute on threadpool threads

Comment: Wrong. :) It does not use the Thread Pool, and nor does TPL (Task.Run and Task.Factory.Start however DOES). Look at [the signature of](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx) `SendAsync`. `ExternalThreading = true`. `SendMailAsync` would be a `TaskCompletionSource` wrapper around that ;)

Answer (score 0):

`SendMailAsync` is just a TPL wrapper around the `SendAsync` method, but neither method uses a thread. Instead it uses a model known as an [IO completion port (IOCP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output_completion_port).

When you call `SendMailAsync`, your thread writes the mail message to the socket connecting to the SMTP server and registers a callback with the operating system which will be executed when the client receives a response back from the server. This callback is triggered by the "completion" event handled by the IO completion port.

The callback itself is invoked on one of a number of IO completion threads which are managed by the thread-pool. This pool of threads just handles the callbacks from IO completion events. Part of completing the callback marks the `Task` returned by the call to `SendMailAsync` as "completed", allowing any awaiting code to start execution in their own context.